# Is it possible to find when two cars will meet given this graph?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, physics, kinematics

The problem is as follows:

> The figure from below shows the speed against time of two cars, one
>   blue and the other orange. It is known that both depart from the same
>   spot. Find the instant on seconds when one catches the other.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The given alternatives are:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&14\,s\\
2.&16\,s\\
3.&20\,s\\
4.&25\,s\\
5.&28\,s\\
\end{array}$

For this problem I attempted to do the "trick" using the areas behind the curves but I couldn't find the answer.

So far I could only state the equations as this: (I'm using $v_{r}=\textrm{orange car}$ and $v_{b}=\textrm{blue car}$

$v_{r}=8$

$v_{b}=t-5$

Since $v=\dfrac{dx}{dt}$

Then:

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=8$

$x(t)=8t+c$

$x(0)=0\,, c=0$

$x(t)_{r}=8t$

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=t-5$

$x(t)=\frac{t^2}{2}-5t+c$

$x(0)=0\, c=0$

$x(t)_{b}= \frac{t^2}{2}-5t$

So by equating both I could obtain the time isn't it?.

$8t=\frac{t^2}{2}-5t$

$0=\frac{t^2}{2}-13t$

$0=t(t-26)$

So time would be $26\,s$ But it doesn't seem to be in any of the alternatives given. Could it be that I'm not getting the right picture of this problem correctly?. Can somebody give me a help?.

Comment: I think your mistake was in saying that the blue car's velocity was $(t-5)$. This implies that the blue car was moving backwards for the first $5$ seconds instead of being stationary.

Answer (score 1):

Velocity is defined as the derivative of the distance function. Let $v_1(t)$ and $v_2(t)$ denote the velocity function for the first and second car respectively. Then, we can express the distance functions, $d_1(t)$ and $d_2(t)$ respectively, as an anti-derivative of the velocity function: $$d_1(t)=\int v_1(t)dt$$ and $$d_2(t)=\int v_2(t)dt.$$

To find when the two cars meet, find the values of $t$ that satisfy $d_1(t)=d_2(t)$, which can be done by integrating the velocity functions and then solving for $t$.

Answer (score 0):

**The mistake in your computations** is that for the second care you set $x(0)=0$. You should have $x(5)=0$

Note that for the second car you have $x'(t)=0$ when $0 \leq t \leq 5$ and $x'(t)=t-5$ when $t \geq 5$.  You need to either start your computations at $t_0=5$ or treat this as a piecewise function.

**Hint** Alternatelly, the areas below the graphs represent the distance traveled. You want the two area below the graph to be equal.

It $t$ is the moment they meey, the area below the first graph is $A=8t$. The area below the second graph is $\frac{1}{2} (t-5)^2$. Make them equal.

Comment: Gee I overlooked that. I'm stuck on why the area of the triangle is $(t-5)^2$? The base is clear that is $t-5$ but **why** the height is also the same?. If I make those two expressions equal I get $t=1$ and $t=25$, which one is to choose from?. I could be guided by the answers but what would be the justification of one over the other?

Comment: You mentioned something about step function. I'm not familiar with them. Perhaps can you put this in your answer so I can see how would had been done by following that route?. I'd like to learn about that part please.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell Note that the small triangle you have has a heigth of $8$ and a basis of $13-5=8$.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell $$v(t)=\left\{ \begin{array}{lc} 0 & \mbox{ if } 0 \leq t \leq 5 \\ t-5 &\mbox{ if } t \geq 5 \end{array} \right.$$ And sorry, I meant piecewise function.

Comment: Oh I see, so I can conclude that because the triangle is  isoceles then the other side must be the same. I'll keep a note about that in my flashcards. But the second part is where I'm stuck on. This piecewise function, what am I supposed to do with it?. Integrate in the given intervals, but integrating zero?. I'm confused about that. Perhaps can you promote your last comment as part of your answer and develop it there a little bit more of how should I had proceeded if I were to follow that method?

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell The antiderivative of $0$ is a constant, and since the original possition is $0$, it is the constant $0$. The antiderivative of $t-5$ is $\frac{1}{2}t^2-5t+C_2$ and since the position at $t=5$ is $0$ you get $C_2=...$

Answer (score 0):

The orange car started moving $5$ seconds before the blue car started. By the time the blue car started moving, the orange car had already covered a $40$ meter distance. Therefore, we can say that:

Orange car distance $(d_o)=8x+40$

Blue car distance $(d_b)=\frac{x^2}{2}$

Now we make both the equations equal to each other, and solve for $x$ (time).

$8x+40=\frac{x^2}{2} \\
16x+80=x^2 \\
0=x^2-16x-80 \\
0=(x-20)(x+4) \\
x=20,-4$

Since we can't have $-4$ seconds, we have to go with $20$ seconds. However, this is not the final answer. The time $20$ seconds just tells us how long it took *after* the blue car started moving for both distances to become equal. In reality, the orange car had already started moving $5$ seconds earlier, so we have to count that time as well. Therefore, the final answer is $25$ seconds.

If you wanted to take $t=0$ as the starting point for both cars (instead of $t=5$), then you would have to go with the advice of N.S. and write the blue car's velocity as a piecewise function.